# Wicket - maven dependency - cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol: class PageParameters

Tags: java, maven, wicket

While working with the "Apache Wicket User Guide" I first used the maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
    <artifactId>wicket</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.17</version>
</dependency>
```

This worked. I see that there are newer versions. So I tried to upgrade to 7.4.0

```
cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol: class PageParameters
```

I tried the following dependencies without success:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
    <artifactId>wicket-core</artifactId>
    <version>7.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
    <artifactId>wicket-extensions</artifactId>
    <version>7.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
    <artifactId>wicket-request</artifactId>
    <version>7.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And is this functionality gone?

```
add( new FeedbackPanel("feedbackMessage", 
    new ExactErrorLevelFilter(FeedbackMessage.ERROR)));
```

Can you help me upgrade and still use PageParameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the import for PageParameters and use your IDE to import it again. PageParameters class has been moved from one package to another in Wicket 1.5.0

Answer (score 1):

`wicket-core` depends on `wicket-request`, following dependency should bring PageParameters class you need

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
    <artifactId>wicket-core</artifactId>
    <version>7.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you. Together with the above hint my issue was solved. I had ALSO to update the log with the right version.